# TS and React State - Argument of type 'RangeModifier' is not assignable to parameter of type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

[image]

I'm getting the above error and I really do not understand what it is asking from me.

I've got a type called state that I pass down like below which I thought is what it was after.

```
type State = {
  from: undefined,
  to: undefined,
  range?: object,
}
```

I made it optional as in the constructor the range state is not set as it isn't needed.

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      from: undefined,
      to: undefined,
    };

    this.handleDayClick = this.handleDayClick.bind(this);
  }
```

And then I'm setting it in the method below where I am getting the error in the screenshot that I've added to the question.

```
handleDayClick(day) {
  const range = DateUtils.addDayToRange(day, this.state);
  const { handleDateUpdate } = this.props;

  handleDateUpdate(range);
  this.setState(range);
}
```

I really don't get how I can resolve this error. I'm new to TS and I'm finding the error messages quite difficult to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setState` accepts an object as the argument:

```
this.setState({to: range.to, from: range.from});
```

Comment: Legend this was the right approach. What I was missing also is in the type I needed to check if it was undefined or a Date type.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the entire state object to the object stored in `range` whereas you just want the `range` attribute to be set. Syntax as below:

```
this.setState({ range });
```